# Matrix with irreducible minimal polynomial gives rise to a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, field-theory

> For a field $K$, $A\in Mat_n(K)$ with minimal polynomial (irreducible) $\mu_A(T)\in K[T]$ with $d=\deg\mu_A(T)$. Let $$E=\left\{\sum_{i=0}^{d-1} a_iA^i: a_i\in K\right\}\subset Mat_n(K).$$ Prove that $E$ is a field.

I started with: Let $$a,b\in E\implies a+b=\sum_{i=0}^{d-1} a_iA^i+\sum_{i=0}^{d-1} b_iA^i=\sum_{i=0}^{d-1} (a_i+b_i)A^i\in E$$$$a,b\in E\implies a\cdot b=\sum_{i=0}^{d-1} a_iA^i\cdot\sum_{i=0}^{d-1} b_iA^i=\ ?$$ **By the multiplication I stucked, is this the right way?**

For neutral element: It is clear that there exists an neutral element for addition, because the coefficients are field elements.

**But what is with the inverse for multiplication?**

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to show that this is a ring ? (and not a field)

Comment: Yes, it said that $E$ with matrix addition and matrix multplication is a field.

Comment: But it is not true that $E$ is a field. For example, take $A \neq 0$ a non invertible matrix. $A \in E$,  but $A$ does not have an inverse for multiplication...

Comment: Well the matrices are invertible, because of the minimal polynomial $\mu_A$

Comment: Yes because you have added the condition $\mu_A$ irreducible.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, was my fault.

Comment: How do you get to $E\simeq K[T]/(\mu_A)$?

Comment: @user26857 I think you take a homomorphism $\phi:K[T]\to E$ but how do you map an element from $K[T]$ to $E$. $x\mapsto ?$

Comment: Isn't this obvious? $T↦A$. In general, $\sum a_iT^i\mapsto\sum a_iA^i$. (Maybe you are worried about the polynomials of degree $\ge d$. Well, $T^d\mapsto A^d$ and since $\mu_A(A)=0$ we get that all powers of $A$ which are greater or equal than $d$ are linear combinations of smaller powers.) In fact, $$E=\{\sum_{i=0}^ma_iA^i:a_i\in K, m\ge0\}.$$

Comment: I would do this the same way as user26857 (may be minor variations in the details). You get a homomorphism of rings from $K[T]$ to $M_n(K)$ by extending $T\mapsto A$.The polynomial $\mu_A(T)$ is in the kernel. Because the ideal $\langle\mu_A(T)\rangle\subset K[T]$ is maximal we can conclude that $\mu_A(T)$ generates the kernel. An argument with dimensions then shows that the image is $E$. When you quotient out a maximal ideal of a commutative ring you get a field. Done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two not obvious points needed to prove are :

1. $a,b \in E \implies ab \in E$
2. Every $a \in E$ such that $a \neq 0$ is invertible.

Let's start with a useful lemma:

**Lemma:** Let $P \in K[X]$. Then $P(A) \in E$.

*Proof:* By Euclidean division, there exists $Q,R \in K[X]$ with $\deg R \leq n-1$ such that $P=\mu_A Q+R$.
Then $P(A)=\mu_A(A) Q(A)+R(A)=R(A) \in E$. $\square$

The first point then follows immediately as for $P,Q \in K[X], \space P(A) Q(A) = PQ(A) \in E$.

As for the second point, let $a \in E$, with $a \neq 0$. We can write $a=P(A)$ with $\deg P \leq n-1$ and $P \neq 0$.

Because $P \neq 0$ ,$\deg P < \deg \mu_A$ and $\mu_A$ is irreducible, we have $\gcd(P,\mu_A)=1$. Hence by Bezout identity, there exist $U,V \in  K[X]$ such that $PU+\mu_A V=1$. Applying $A$ to this identity, we get $P(A) U(A)=I$ with $U(A) \in E$ by the lemma. Which shows that $P(A)=a$ is invertible. QED.

Comment: Very very nice!